# How to set up theano config

Tags: theano

I'm new to Theano.
Trying to set up a config file.

First of all, I notice that I have no .theanorc file:

1. `locate .theanorc` - returns nothing
2. `echo $THEANORC` - returns nothing
3. `theano.test()` - passes ok

I'm guessing some default configuration was created wen i installed theano. Where is it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Theano does not create any configuration file by itself, but has default values for all its configuration flags. You only need such a file if you want to modify the default values.

This can be done by creating a .theanorc file in your home directory. For example, if you want floatX to be always float32, you can do this:

```
echo -e "\n[global]\nfloatX=float32\n" >> ~/.theanorc
```

under Linux and Mac. Under windows, this can also be done. See this page for more details:

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html

Comment: What is the `$home` they say in the theano config link? How can I find it on Windows?

Comment: You can also set environment variables using `export THEANO_FLAGS="floatX=float32,device=opencl0:1,openmp=True"` in your `.bashrc` or equivalent. The environment variable format can be useful if you want to temporarily alter Theano's config for a single command.

Answer (score 10):

In Linux in terminal Home directory write:

```
nano .theanorc
```

In the file copy the following lines

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu0

[lib]
cnmem = 1
```

Save it.

When I import theano in python I was having cnmem memory problems. Seems that is because the monitor is connected to the gpu. To resolve it change cnmem to 0.8. This number below 1 is the percentage of gpu reserved for theano

Comment: when I followed your instructions, I started to get `ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): nvcc compiler not found on $PATH. Check your nvcc installation and try again.` I think [nvcc] needs to be defined in the .theanorc file as well.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 with 1080 ti gpu.  I did not include cnmem = 1 and device = cuda

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar question and this is what helped me:

```
import theano
//...
theano.config.floatX = 'float32' //or 'float64' whatever you want
```

Comment: Please explain what each line does.

Comment: you cannot set device = 'gpu' (after initialization) in this manner though, you need to create a .theanorc file under /HOME for this

Comment: Also, if you use float64 with Theano, you can't use the the GPU version. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35998515/why-does-the-floatxs-flag-impact-whether-gpu-is-used-in-theano?rq=1

Comment: @Rhubarb in windows, where to create the `.theanorc.txt` file and how to make theano able to see it?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
nano ~/.theanorc
```

Then I entered:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = cuda
```

Code to check if Theano is using the GPU is on the [Theano doc page](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html).

(I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Theano 0.9.0 (conda), NVIDIA 1080 Ti GPU).

Answer (score 1):

I have been having similar problems. I have NVIDIA 1070 GPU on a desktop machine with Asus Z270E motherboard and was able to import theano after setting up the .theanorc file as below. (And rebooting afterwards)

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = gpu

[cuda]
root = /usr/local/cuda
[lib]
cnmem = 1
```