# Why does the floatX's flag impact whether GPU is used in Theano?

Tags: python, gpu, theano

I am testing Theano with GPU using the [script provided in the tutorial for that purpose](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html#testing-theano-with-gpu):

```
# Start gpu_test.py
# From http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html#using-gpu
from theano import function, config, shared, sandbox
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy
import time

vlen = 10 * 30 * 768  # 10 x #cores x # threads per core
iters = 1000

rng = numpy.random.RandomState(22)
x = shared(numpy.asarray(rng.rand(vlen), config.floatX))
f = function([], T.exp(x))
print(f.maker.fgraph.toposort())
t0 = time.time()
for i in xrange(iters):
    r = f()
t1 = time.time()
print("Looping %d times took %f seconds" % (iters, t1 - t0))
print("Result is %s" % (r,))
if numpy.any([isinstance(x.op, T.Elemwise) for x in f.maker.fgraph.toposort()]):
    print('Used the cpu')
else:
    print('Used the gpu')
# End gpu_test.py
```

If I specify `floatX=float32`, it runs on GPU:

```
francky@here:/fun$ THEANO_FLAGS='mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu2,floatX=float32' python gpu_test.py
Using gpu device 2: GeForce GTX TITAN X (CNMeM is disabled)
[GpuElemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector)>), HostFromGpu(Gp
Looping 1000 times took 1.458473 seconds
Result is [ 1.23178029  1.61879349  1.52278066 ...,  2.20771813  2.29967761
  1.62323296]
Used the gpu
```

If I do not specify `floatX=float32`, it runs on CPU:

```
francky@here:/fun$ THEANO_FLAGS='mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu2'
Using gpu device 2: GeForce GTX TITAN X (CNMeM is disabled)
[Elemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<TensorType(float64, vector)>)]
Looping 1000 times took 3.086261 seconds
Result is [ 1.23178032  1.61879341  1.52278065 ...,  2.20771815  2.29967753
  1.62323285]
Used the cpu
```

If I specify `floatX=float64`, it runs on CPU:

```
francky@here:/fun$ THEANO_FLAGS='mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu2,floatX=float64' python gpu_test.py
Using gpu device 2: GeForce GTX TITAN X (CNMeM is disabled)
[Elemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<TensorType(float64, vector)>)]
Looping 1000 times took 3.148040 seconds
Result is [ 1.23178032  1.61879341  1.52278065 ...,  2.20771815  2.29967753
  1.62323285]
Used the cpu
```

Why does the `floatX` flag impact whether GPU is used in Theano?

I use:

- Theano 0.7.0 (according to `pip freeze`),
- Python 2.7.6 64 bits (according to `import platform; platform.architecture()`),
- Nvidia-smi 361.28 (according to `nvidia-smi`),
- CUDA 7.5.17 (according to `nvcc --version`),
- GeForce GTX Titan X (according to `nvidia-smi`),
- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64 (according to `lsb_release -a` and `uname -i`).

I read the documentation on [`floatX`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html#config.floatX) but it didn't help. It simply says:

> `config.floatX`
>  String value: either ‘float64’ or ‘float32’
>   Default: ‘float64’
>
> This sets the default dtype returned by tensor.matrix(),
>   tensor.vector(), and similar functions. It also sets the default
>   theano bit width for arguments passed as Python floating-point
>   numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's because they haven't yet implemented float64 for GPUs.

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html :

> Only computations with float32 data-type can be accelerated. Better support for float64 is expected in upcoming hardware but float64 computations are still relatively slow (Jan 2010).

Answer (score 2):

From http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html#gpuarray-backend I read that it is possible to perform float64 calculations on GPU, but you have to install the `libgpuarray` from source.

I managed to install it, see [this script](https://gist.github.com/gaebor/61323e72a7b415e6487e9590ce181857), I used [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), you don't even have to have `sudo`.

After installation you can use the old backend with [config flag](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html) `device=gpu` and the new backend with `device=cuda`.

The new backend can perform 64 bit calculations, but it works differently for me. Some operations stopped working. `ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by applicable law` :)

Comment: Thanks, interesting.

Comment: update: https://github.com/Theano/Theano/wiki/Converting-to-the-new-gpu-back-end%28gpuarray%29